# performance penalty when using "join with temp table " in contrast of "IN clause with constant values"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have a temp table with two records like this:

```
select * into #Tbl from (select 1 id union select 2) tbl
```

and also the related index:

```
Create nonclustered index IX_1 on #T(id)
```

The following query takes **4000ms** to run:

```
SELECT   AncestorId
FROM     myView 
WHERE    AncestorId =ANY(select id from #t)
```

But the equivalent query (with `IN` and literal values) takes only **3ms** to run!:

```
SELECT  ProjectStructureId
FROM    myView
WHERE   AncestorId in (1,2)
```

Why this huge difference and how can I change the first query to be as fast as the second one?

**P.S.**

1. SQL SERVER 2014 SP2
2. myView is a Recursive CTE
3. Changing the first query to `INNER JOIN` model or `EXISTS` model didn't help
4. Changing the `IX_1 Index` to a cluster index didn't help
5. Using `FORSEEK` didn't help

**P.S.2**

The execution plans of both can be downloaded here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/pas1ovyamqojhba/Query-With-In.sqlplan?dl=0

Execution plans in [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByNP4vGex)

**P.S. 3**

The view definition is :

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[myView] 
AS
WITH parents AS (SELECT        main.Id, main.NodeTypeCode, main.ParentProjectStructureId AS DirectParentId, parentInfo.Id AS AncestorId, parentInfo.ParentProjectStructureId AS AncestorParentId, CASE WHEN main.NodeTypeCode <> IsNull(parentInfo.NodeTypeCode, 0) 
                                                   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AncestorTypeDiffLevel
                          FROM            dbo.ProjectStructures AS main LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                   dbo.ProjectStructures AS parentInfo ON main.ParentProjectStructureId = parentInfo.Id
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT        m.Id, m.NodeTypeCode, m.ParentProjectStructureId, parents.AncestorId, parents.AncestorParentId,
                                                   CASE WHEN m.NodeTypeCode <> parents.NodeTypeCode THEN AncestorTypeDiffLevel + 1 ELSE AncestorTypeDiffLevel END AS AncestorTypeDiffLevel

                          FROM            dbo.ProjectStructures AS m INNER JOIN
                                                   parents ON m.ParentProjectStructureId = parents.Id)
    SELECT          ISNULL(Id, - 1) AS ProjectStructureId, 
                    ISNULL(NodeTypeCode,-1) NodeTypeCode,
                    DirectParentId, 
                    ISNULL(AncestorId, - 1) AS AncestorId, 
                    AncestorParentId, 
                    AncestorTypeDiffLevel
    FROM            parents
    WHERE        (AncestorId IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: (1) For anyone to help, you would have to show the definition of `myView`.  (2) To help yourself, learn how to read execution plans.

Comment: Just curious.  What is the performance of WHERE  AncestorId IN (select id from #t)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will post it right now

Comment: @JohnCappelletti it is the same

Comment: temp tables are stored on disk, Or in virtual disk memory space, and undergo all the overhead associated with storage of data in any table, including ACID checks, transactional support logging ,etc. etc. the use of `IN` is restricted to the code executing in the query processor.

Comment: Do you get consistent results with consecutive runs?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti unfortunately Yes!

Comment: I added the execution plans too

Comment: The problem clearly is the hash match (+ the fact that it requires all rows to be fetched from the view). Could be related to statistics, is your AncestorId distributed unevenly? Might also be just that recursive CTEs inside views aren't optimized that well. You could also try to use an inline table valued function with AncestorId as a parameter instead.

Comment: @JamesZ thanks for your details. But what do you mean by using TVFs? Specially when AncestorId is an array of ids?

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej Select from your temp. table, cross apply the function and use the column from the temp. table as the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your good plan it is able to push the literal values right into the index seek of the anchor part of the recursive CTE.

[image]

It refuses to do that when they come from a table.

You could create a table type

```
CREATE TYPE IntegerSet AS TABLE 
( 
Integer int PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
);
```

And then pass that to an inline TVF written to use that in the anchor part directly.

Then just call it like

```
DECLARE @AncestorIds INTEGERSET;

INSERT INTO @AncestorIds
VALUES      (1),
            (2);

SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[myFn](@AncestorIds);
```

The inline TVF would be much the same as the view but with

```
 WHERE parentInfo.Id IN (SELECT Integer FROM @AncestorIds)
```

in the anchor part of the recursive CTE.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[myFn]
(
@AncestorIds IntegerSet READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
  WITH parents
       AS (SELECT  /*omitted for clarity*/
           WHERE parentInfo.Id IN (SELECT Integer FROM @AncestorIds)
           UNION ALL
           SELECT/* Rest omitted for clarity*/
```

Also you might as well change that `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` though the optimiser does that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. anyway I cannot change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN because of the tree root record loss unless "union" the root record with the "inner join" result. so is it efficient?

Comment: I changed LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN and removing the WHERE clause condition but there was no change. Both plans have 50% of execution time

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej I wasn't suggesting that as a fix for your issue. Your where clause changes the left join back to an inner join anyway (look at th execution plan and see that all the joins are inner joins) so I was suggesting you just write it as an inner join anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that I would write the query as:

```
SELECT AncestorId
FROM myView 
WHERE AncestorId IN (select id from #t);
```

I doubt this would help.

The issue is that SQL Server can optimize literal values better than values inside a table.  The result is that the execution plan changes.

If neither `IN` nor `JOIN` fix the problem, then you probably have to fiddle with the definition of the view to improve performance.

Comment: As I told in comment, it doesn't changed the result

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej . . . Start by running the full query without the view.